# How to send/receive serial communication

Tags: serial-port, arduino, serial-communication

How can I send a string via serial communications from Java or Python?  I have a very little arduino program that will recieve a CSV string of ints that each control different relays (I adapted it from their example).

I just got an Arduino, and I am trying to use it to open and close a relay remotely.  I have it opening and closing the relay, no problem.  But I really have no idea where to start as far as using serial communication.

I have a bluetooth dongle that I can connect to, but once I do that I'm lost.

Also, this is my first time using serial communications AND my first time using an Arduino.  So I'm sorry if I am completely off on some of the things I am asking.  All I know is what I've learned from Google.

Thank you very much

Comment: You should take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11051973/390829

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any Java or Python serial port classes and methods.  There is however one thing you need to be aware of.

The newer arduino's have a feature known as AutoReset.  This works by connecting the DTR signal from the serial port to the Reset line on the chip using a capacitor or such.  The IDE uses this to reset the board to activate the bootloader and initiate uploading code to the arduino.  The serial monitor in the IDE is aware of this and does not toggle the DTR line when comunicating with the device (except when it initially connects).

There is are several ways to defeat this feature and you can [read about them here](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection).

As for actually comunicating with the device, there are several tutorials about serial communication in both Java and Python.

[Pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) includes the option to not use the DTR lines when opening a port.

Here is [a website](http://silveiraneto.net/2009/03/01/arduino-and-java/) explaining how to use RXTX (a Java library) to comunicate with an Arduino

Best of luck.